# Correcting misprints as separate edit

Tags: discussion

Is there any sense to suggest or make edit which corrects one or several misprints in question?

It may enhance readability of question in general but I am not sure if this can be a separate edit.

Comment: Could you give a concise sample of what you mean please?

Comment: I don't mean specific question but sometimes it may be difficult to understand the question because of several misprints (bad English or user was in a hurry). Does it make sense to fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. In fact, that's what edits are for!

Every improvement you can make to the post, suggest an edit for. If the edit is good and constructive and makes the post easier to read or clearer, it will be approved (And you'll be awarded with 2 reputation points too!)

Comment: Though if you decide to improve a post, try your best to be comprehensive.